# How do I make a button redirect to a specific url based on a known parameter of the PC being used?

Tags: javascript

I have a number of manuals for different machines available on my company intranet.   Each machine has a PC terminal that the machine operator would use to access these manuals and other reference materials. Right now, the user clicks a button and is redirected to the list of available machine manuals. To improve the UX, I want to, on click, direct the user to the specific manual for the machine with which the PC terminal is associated. There is no need for them to have to sort through the full list of manuals.

Is there a way to use an known identifier (MAC?) for the specific PC to direct them to the correct URL for their respective manual, presumably using a series of if statements? If it matters, the number of PCs I'm dealing with is finite and I have access to them.

Comment: You can't use the MAC address, what different PC types are there? Operating System?

Comment: They should all be desktops running windows 8

Answer (score 0):

Use the windows hostname command or COMPUTERNAME environment variable.